# Eclipse shortcut: next item in Content Assist pop-up menu of choices

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to bind a keyboard shortcut to the action of selecting the next item in a Content Assist pop-up menu of choices?

---

Desired configuration:

- press `OPTION /` to invoke the Content Assist pop-up menu
- press `CONTROL N` to navigate down the Content Assist pop-up menu items until I highlight the one I want

I know this is possible as I know somebody who can do just that in his Eclipse.. I used it and it worked.

Comment: Kepler seems to be working..

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

In "Preference" - "Keys", find your combination of keys to move cursor one line up/down (search command "Line up"/"Line down"), and set its scope to "In Dialog/Window" to make it work in Content Assist prompt.

Note that this configuration **doesn't** make it work in all windows. At least, not in "Open Source..." (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).